# Ldap/php, check if an (ldap)user belongs to an (ldap)group to grant access to an (ldap)app

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

My main question is : 
How to check that an ldap user has access to an ldap app.

My ldap schema :

```
ou=apps
----subsonic
--------subsonic url
----owncloud
--------owncloud url
________________________
ou=groups 
----subsonicGroup
----owncloudGroup
______________________
ou=people
----john
_______________
ou=servers
----server1
__________________
```

What I want to set for example is :

- The subsonic app got a 'url'
- The subsonic group is allowed to access, subsonic app (url)
- The user 'john' could be either a member of the subsonicGroup,or also a member of the owncloud group or member of 0 groups

Then, I'll just have to check which group John could be a member of to give him access or not.

So which classobject and attributes should I use to do this ?

Also should I use ldap access list ?

(To communicate with opendldap in my app, I use php)

Thanks a lot for your future reply and advices

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: Your second question is not really constructive, and won't be useful for other users.

Comment: i took it off, thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you already some code? Do you want to code from scratch or are you using a Framework?

Comment: Hello, I have already written my own php framework. My main question is about the ldap schema, witch objectclass attributes should i use.

Comment: As i tried it seems for example the posix group and posix account object classes is able to accept multigroup user ...

Comment: But which objectclass should I use for a server, and for an app ?